# pdfbox convert pdf to img, Some Chinese are incomplete

Tags: pdfbox

```
    public void pdf2img() throws IOException {
        String url = "xxxx";
        byte[] pdfByteArray = downloadFile(url);
        PDDocument document = Loader.loadPDF(pdfByteArray);
        PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
        int totalPage = document.getNumberOfPages();
        BufferedImage[] bufferedImages = new BufferedImage[totalPage];
        for (int i = 0; i < totalPage; i++) {
            BufferedImage image = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(i, 180, ImageType.RGB);
            image.flush();
            bufferedImages[i] = image;
        }

        merge(bufferedImages);
    }
```

[this is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bCOY.jpg)
[this is my input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ludRJ.jpg)

Does anyone know what is the reason for this? Is it because of missing fonts or other reasons? PDFbox 3.0.0 cannot find the place to set the fonts.

Comment: The current version is 3.0.1 and you haven't explained what is missing.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! pardon me for being dumb and unable to read chinese characters, are some characters missing or the font mismatched with the one in pdf?

Comment: you are right, some Chinese are incomplete

Comment: @TilmanHausherr some Chinese are incomplete, you can see my input and my output

Comment: Known and unsolved problem, sadly  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3293

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr thank you!